# how can i trigger formkey validate on initState - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, validation, flutter-textformfield

When the user comes to the profile edit page, I want to trigger the validation of the empty fields in the form and have them drawn in red. How can I do that?

I don't think I need to share any code blocks because I want to trigger formKey's validate method when the page is opened.

Answer (score 2):

Use `AutovalidateMode.always`

```dart
TextFormField(
 autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
   ....  
 )
```

Comment: This will validate way more than on just the initial render